# Error while Detaching Entities in Entity Framework v1

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1.
Using VS2008 Designer, I created entity 'Category' based on table 'Category' and 'AppUser' based on table 'AppUser' and 'AppUserDetail' based on table 'AppUserDetail'.

```
DB TABLES:
CREATE TABLE  [Category](
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([CategoryId])
) 
CREATE TABLE  [AppUser](
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY ([UserId]),
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category(CategoryId) ON DELETE CASCADE
) 
CREATE TABLE AppUserDetail ( 
    DetailId        int     NOT NULL, 
    UserId      int     not null, 
    Address         varchar(2000)   not null,
    Comments        varchar(2000)   not null,   
    PRIMARY KEY ([DetailId] ),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES AppUser(UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
TABLE RECORDS:
Category:   1, Category-1
AppUser:    1, User1, 1
AppUserDetail:  1, 1, Address-1, Comments-1
```

Using following code,I retrieve a user and then try to detach all entities in context.

```
using (var context = new MyEntities()) {
    AppUser user = context.AppUserSet.Where(u => u.UserId == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    //Detach ALL entities
    foreach (var stateEntry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)) {            
        if (!stateEntry.IsRelationship)
        context.Detach(stateEntry.Entity);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="The object is in a detached state. This operation cannot be performed on an ObjectStateEntry when the object is detached."
  Source="System.Data.Entity"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateEntry.get_IsRelationship()
```

In code I'm only selecting entities which are not Detached.

Please tell what is cause of this error ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hesitate to ask why you're doing this, but:

When you Detach an entity, *the entire graph of related entities* is detached. So later in your loop you go to Detach one of those related entities and it's already been detached implicitly by an earlier iteration.

Comment: Thanks. But MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx) says 
"Only the entity is removed; if there are any related objects that are being tracked by the same ObjectStateManager, those will not be detached automatically"

Comment: I presumed it worked the same as Attach, which certainly behaves as I describe. But you're right; that's what the docs say. Test this and see who is right. It would account for the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to detach all entities?

Maybe you can try to use the **Context.MergeOption** property to retrieve a list of detached entities directly so you don't need to detach them.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx

Davide

Comment: MergeOption is on ObjectQuery, not ObjectContext. But +1 anyway for a better solution than Detaching.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, and it is just a guess, is that deleted items are detached too? It might be worth testing.

Could you change your code so you ignore deleted items?

i.e:

```
foreach (var stateEntry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
     EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged
)) {                    
   if (!stateEntry.IsRelationship)        
       context.Detach(stateEntry.Entity);    
}
```

Alex